# Is there a way to customize the Docker machine UUID and VMID

Tags: linux, docker

I am currently attempting to create a trusted file storage for a licensing engine called FlexNET in a Docker container, the problem is that the licensing engine requires me to have a persistent UUID, VMID and MAC Address.

I have found how to set the MAC Address of the container. But I have trouble setting the UUID and VMID of the docker container.

As far as I see the licensing engine reads the UUID from:

```
/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
```

Which is linked to the kernel and therefore cannot be modified directly.

So my question is: Is there a way to modify the contents of this file from Docker without having to rebuild the host OS kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to change `product_uuid`, if I understand your question correctly.

### Mounting over product_uuid

You can bind mount a file from the host into that path in the container. So instead of a call to sysfs when reading that path, it will read the mounted file.

For example:

```
$ echo "new-uuid" > /var/tmp/product_uuid
$ docker run --rm -ti -v /var/tmp/product_uuid:/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid centos bash
[root@217e12a74e74 /]# cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
new-uuid
```

### chroot inside the image

If you do not want to have to mount in the file, and want this completely contained within the container, another way to do this is with a chroot when building the image.

Following is an example Dockerfile which sets up a shell inside a `chroot` :

```
FROM centos:7

RUN mkdir -p /chroot /chroot/sys/class/dmi/id \
  && cp -al /lib /lib64/ /usr/ chroot/ || echo "Ignoring linking issues ..." \
  && echo "new-uuid" > /chroot/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid

CMD chroot /chroot sh
```

When we launch this, it will launch a shell by default inside our chroot:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm uuid-test 
sh-4.2# cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
new-uuid
```

For your use case you'd need to also add your application and its dependencies to the `chroot`, and also replace `sh` with the applications startup command. Note too that this means `/sys/` will *only* contain the file `/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid`.

### Other ways?

Off the top of my head I'm not sure of any other straightforward way to do this, as docker will always mount sysfs to `/sys` - unless you specify `/sys` as a VOLUME in the Dockerfile, but I don't think that will help here.